# How to center a text line in a navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I am really new in css and I am experimenting how to create a googe landing page which is part of my course I am taking, and I am starting on navigation bar, Even though I already used inline-block, the text is still below the text line and not on its' center, my code is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Homepage</title>
<style type="text/css">



    .navigation {
        width: 400;
        text-align: right;
    }

    .navigation ul {
         list-style-type: none;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         overflow: hidden;
    }

    .navigation li {

        display:inline-block;
        text-decoration:none; 
    }

    .navigation ul li a {  
    text-decoration:none; 
    padding:0 12px;
    }

    .navigation  #profile-image {
        text-align: center;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navigation">

<ul>
    <li style="margin: 5px auto;"> Glendon Philipp </li>
    <li> <a href="#news"> Gmail </a>    </li>
    <li> <a href="#contact"> <img src="img/google-button.jpeg"> </a>    </li>
    <li> <a href="#about"> <img src="img/google-button-notification.jpg"> </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#profile-image"> <img id="profile-image" src="img/profile.jpg"> </a></li>
</ul>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want the text aligned to the middle of your containing div?

Comment: yes middle of it aligned with the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go:

```
.navigation li {    
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-decoration:none; 
    }
```

This will align your text to the vertical middle of your images. You will need to tweak your margins and padding though.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s04o30ya/

Comment: thank you, it is what i need, the vertical align, i tried to float right on ul and float left on li but this vertical is problem.

Comment: No worries, I would say go to css-tricks.com and take a look at the ways some interesting things are done there.

Comment: yes I will definitely check it, thank you, I'm on course now  from lynda.com and theodinproject.com is there any site you can recommend? it's really hard to be self taught, don't know where to start with great resources..

Comment: codeacademy.com, lynda.com, css-tricks.com, all else fails, youtube it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this ok for you ?

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwyrc8uh/1/)

```
.navigation ul {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     text-align: center;
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

By the way, this is incorrect :

```
.navigation {
    width: 400;
    text-align: right;
}
```

You have to add a value of the width like for example :

```
.navigation {
    width: 400px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: His question was a bit confusing, but he actually wanted vertical alignment, not horizontal.